# Take value from text field and perform jquery when submit is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, onkeydown

I have the following text field:

```
<input type="password" id="seed" placeholder="Enter Seed" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { setSeed(value.toUpperCase()); refreshPage(); }"/>
```

This does a function when I enter input and press enter. I have now added a submit button underneath which I want to do the same function when clicked.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { setSeed(value.toUpperCase()); refreshPage(); }">
```

Could someone help tell me how I refer to the value in the text field. Also if "onkeydown" is correct e.g. it shouldn't be something like "onclick".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.getElementById("seed").value is a correct way to get value from input field.

as for the submit event - I would recommend to bind a submit event of the form element, it covers all the events you want to handle.

Comment: That worked thanks! I did: <button onclick="setSeed(document.getElementById('seed').value.toUpperCase()); refreshPage();">Click me</button> instead of submit. However I just realised it doesn't do if (event.keyCode == 13) { how can I verify that?

Comment: Just realised event.keyCode refers to the enter key so isn't relevant. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a library like jQuery you can refer to the textfield element by its ID with something like this:

```
$("#seed")
```

If you are not using any library you can refer to the textfield using the function getElementById:

```
document.getElementById("seed")
```